# Square numbers in the form $1+4y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

I want to solve the equation $y+x=x^2$:
$$
x^2-x-y=0 \\ x_{1;2}=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1+4y}}{2}
$$

However I want the solutions to be only natural numbers; the question then turns to find values of $y$ such that $1+4y$ is always a square number. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\bf 1&4 & \bf 9 & 16 & \bf 25 & 36 &\bf 49 &\ldots \\ \hline
4\cdot {\bf 0}+1 & &4\cdot{\bf 2} + 1 && 4\cdot {\bf 6} + 1 && 4 \cdot {\bf 12} + 1 & \ldots
\end{array}

Answer (score 2):

If $1+4y$ is a square, it means that there exists $z\in \Bbb N$ such that $$z^2=1+4y.$$
Therefore, solving for $y$,
$$y=\frac{z^2-1}{4},$$
and that is the expression of the $y$'s you are looking for.

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants $z$ to be odd so that $x$ is an integer.

Comment: Yes but then the question would turn in "when does $\frac{z^2 -1}{4}$ equals to a square number?"

Comment: @Peterix If $y=(z^2-1)/4$ (for $z$ an odd number), then $1+4y=z^2$ is a square. Why should also $y$ be a square?

Comment: I guess he meant "when is $\frac{z^2-1}{4}$ a natural number?"

Answer (score 2):

If you want $x$ and $y$ to be natural number then you correctly found that $1+4y$ must be a square.

So there exists $z \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$
z^2 = 1+4y
$$

It is pretty obvious that $z$ is odd. So you can rewrite $z$ as:

$$
\exists p \in \mathbb{N}, \quad z = 2p+1
$$

Then you substitute and get:

$$
(2p+1)^2 = 1+4y \\
\Leftrightarrow 1+4p(p+1) = 1+4y
$$

You can identify: $y = p(p+1)$ This is a necessary condition for the equation to have a solution.

Then we check that if $p \in \mathbb{N}$, and $y = p(p+1)$ satisfies the equation.
According to your own finding we then have:

$$
x_1 = (1+z)/2 = (1+2p+1)/2 = p+1 \\
x_2 = (1-z)/2 = (1-2p-1)/2 = -p
$$

As we want $x \in \mathbb{N}$ we cannot have $x < 0$. So the solution are:

$$
\forall p \in \mathbb{N}, \quad x = p+1, \quad y = p(p+1)
$$